# can itextsharp support overlaying text?

Tags: c#, itext

I have to overlay some text to text. Can itextsharp do this? I'm creating a form that must need not change it format and also include a variable. Like this

```
THIS AUTHORIZE: ___(variable)_________________
```

Comment: Yes. Also, I recommend using new iText7 instead of the old ITextSharp.

Comment: i can't find documents in google regarding that. Will you mind linking it?

Comment: IText5 examples - http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples-itext5
IText7 examples - http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples-itext7

The examples are in Java but you should be able to use the same definitions for C#.

Comment: You mention *variables*. Do you mean that you put certain text pieces into the page content that shall eventually be replaced? That would be a bad idea, *replacing* content parts in a pdf can be a hassle. You should use form fields instead.

Comment: @mkl before going to the pdf. a form would be filled up first before it will be printed :)